# Relational division

Tags: relational-algebra

I try to understand how the relational division can be expressed by primitive operations of the relational algebra. So, I found this formula (I writed it such as I found it in the same format):
$A \DIVIDEBY B = A[X] \MINUS ((A[X] \TIMES B) \MINUS A)[X]$
But I can't get this. If we use $\TIMES$ (the Cartesian product) then A and B relations can't have same attributes, so we need to rename these attributes, i.e.:
If we have $A \{A_1, A_2, A_3\};B \{A_1, A_2, A_4\}$
then the header of the result relation will be
$\{A_{11},A_{21},A_3,A_{12},A_{22},A_4\}$,
it's okay... But next I need to apply $\MINUS$ but I can't make it because my relation header diffs from $A$.
It means that it requires yet operations (i.e. $\PROJECT$ and $\RENAME$), it isn't? Can anyone explain me more details by this expression?

Comment: Your pseudo-LaTeX doesn't work. Please fix. What I can read looks wrong. The LHS has no $X$ whereas it is a free variable of the RHS. Finally, it might help if you named the source of the formula that you find confusing.

Comment: @Kai, it's from the book: [C.J. Date - An Introduction to Database Systems (8th Edition)](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Database-Systems-8th/dp/0321197844).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual form of Division requires that the attributes in `B` are a subset of the attributes in `A`. And the result of the Division has just the attributes particular to `A` -- that is `A[X]` in your formulation.

I'm not sure if you understand that `A[X]` **is** a projection. So the Heading of `A[X] TIMES B` is exactly the Heading of `A`. So the inner MINUS is dealing with the same Headings -- that is, Heading of `A`. Then the `[X]` at the end of the formula is again a projection; so the outer MINUS is also dealing with the same Headings -- this time `[X]`.

This answers much the same question (using a different notation):
[Expressing division in relational algebra in terms of other operations](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/70068/expressing-division-in-relational-algebra-in-terms-of-other-operations)
See my comments about the various different forms of 'Relational Division'.

And please note: relations have *Headings*, not 'Headers'.